# mysterious Null Pointer Exception with Simple XML serializer.write

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I'm having trouble using [Simple Xml Serializer](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) to build a Message from a complex object in my android project. The strange part is that it worked fine yesterday; the serialized object was written to a StringWriter and all was well. For some reason I now get this:

```
03-08 12:01:12.884: WARN/System.err(444): java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.write(Traverser.java:225)
   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.write(Traverser.java:208)
     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.write(Traverser.java:186)
   at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1187)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1169)
    at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1147)
```

It keeps blowing up on the serializer.write() line and I can't figure out why.

```
//xmlMsg is the object to be serialized.
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
StringWriter outMsg = null;
serializer.write(xmlMsg, outMsg);
```

Comment: javadoc for the persister interface: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Serializer.html

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize the StringWriter before using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the javadoc it seems reasonable to me that the method will attempt to write to the `Writer` parameter, thus it shouldn't be `null`.

Comment: I put on my robe and dunce hat...
I guess I've just been staring at this too long.. yeah, thats it..